# Items disappeared from Toolbox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've been using VS2008 to build ASP.NET apps with no problems.  Recently, I noticed some important items disappeared from the toolbox, like label and gridview.  I put them back, but I thought it was weird that they just disappeared, as I'm sure I didn't remove them.  Is this something I should be concerned about?  Probably not, pretty minor anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens sometimes, tends to be after installing 3rd party components.

Run the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt, type devenv /resetsettings.
This will reset to VS's default settings, so you'll likely want to back up your settings first Tools > Import and Export settings > Export.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've got all the latest patches for your VS2008? From [this site](http://weblogs.asp.net/javiervillarreal/archive/2008/01/15/visual-studio-not-showing-properly-the-toolbox-items.aspx), try :

> If you have any trouble using the
>   toolbox items in visual studio, just
>   delete the hidden files:
>        toolbox.tbd, toolbox_reset.tbd, toolboxIndex.tbd,
>   toolboxIndex_reset.tbd
>       in
>       drive:\Documents and Settings\\Local
>   Settings\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
>       Ex:
>       C:\Documents and Settings\JAVIER.VILLARREAL\Local
>   Settings\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0
>       Start Visual Studio, and it will reset the toolbox items in the correct
>   form.

Also, there are a few suggestions in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198691/why-do-my-toolbox-items-disappear-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 1):

Happens every so often to me but I don't know the cause.  Whenever I find that I'm beginning to miss things I right click on the Toolbox and select "Reset Toolbox".